# How to create video view full screen inside frame layout or linear Layout

Tags: android, xml, android-videoview, android-framelayout

I have placed Video View and Image View and Text View in FrameLayout i have a problem playing the video in full screen. I want to use only Frame or Linear Layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/vvhotsoptPass"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: can you pls post your layout file with Video View and Image View and Text View in FrameLayout as you said you have placed these views?

Comment: use this code requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
  getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);   before setting setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  it will come in full screen of activity

Answer (score 2):

Try this, it solved my problem.

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
android.widget.FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = (android.widget.FrameLayout.LayoutParams) videoView.getLayoutParams();
params.width =  metrics.widthPixels;
params.height = metrics.heightPixels;
params.leftMargin = 0;
videoView.setLayoutParams(params);
```